# Analyzing a heap dump with leaked SSLSocketImpl

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, memory-leaks, heap-dump

I have an application that runs on Amazon EC2 (using several AWS products such as S3, DynamoDB, etc.) and has a memory leak.  I collected some heap dumps and ran them through Eclipse's Memory Analyzer Tool, which pinpointed several hundred instances of `sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl` (taking up dozens of MB of memory) as probable leaks.

I'm having trouble however figuring out why these `SSLSocketImpl` objects haven't been disposed of.

most instances of `SSLSocketImpl` in the dumps have two references, one from `java.lang.ref.Finalizer`, and one from `com.amazonaws.internal.SdkSSLSocket`.  the Finalizer thread in my heap dump is reported as idle, with no objects awaiting finalization.  but the `com.amazonaws.internal.SdkSSLSocket` objects that have references to the leaked `SSLSocketImpl` objects seem to have been cleaned up.  at least, I can't find them in the heap dump (Dominator view in MAT).

I'm new to analyzing java heap dumps.  what should I look for next?  if the Amazon `SdkSSLSocket` objects have indeed been cleaned up, why weren't the `SSLSocketImpl` objects also cleaned up?

thanks!

Comment: Did you find something?

Comment: never did get to the root of this.  it's been kicked down the road for months now, since deploying new instances has the side effect of making memory leaks a non-issue.

Comment: which EC2 instances have you been using?

Comment: I believe we have this issue as well. I wonder if upgrading the sdk will solve this issue

Answer (score 3):

This could possibly be because of not setting the SSL session cache size, which by default is infinite and that could end up consuming a huge amount of heap space. Setting javax.net.ssl.sessionCacheSize = 1000 should help.

Answer (score 3):

I think I ran into this as well. After messing around with MAT a bit I was able to root cause what's going on, or at least prevent G1GC from doing a full GC on tenured space. Here's the mat diagram I was looking at:

[image]

My application is a simple Spring boot reactive http server which proxy's a reasonable volume of database read calls. I was running single CPU in docker container on K8s with about 4GB of mem. I doubled this to 8GB of mem and still saw the problem.

I didn't believe this was a memory leak because I could observe full GC's being able to cleanup tenured space it would just take a while.

What I believe JDBC is doing is as TCP connections are being **Abandoned** they get relegated to a thread called the *AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread*.

`So what the solution turned out to be was just giving the JVM an extra CPU to service the AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread`.

As soon as I did this my tenured space size never grew and g1_old_space would grow at about the size tenured space was, however my G1 is able to clean g1_old_space more effectively than tenured so long application pauses went away and G1 respected my **-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis**